# Powershell web request - 400 Bad Request

Tags: rest, powershell, http-status-code-400, system.net.webexception

Im building a powershell script to execute commands on a REST-like server, I am using powershell to POST XML data to the webservice. Everything is working perfectly except when the "application" produces an error. The application replies back with details in xml and also gives me a Web Request Error (in this case 400) which is when i have problems. Whenever i get a Web Request Error that is not 200 the commands throw an error which screws up how i handle the error.

This is an example of the response im receiving (using fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 29 Nov 2012 04:29:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Status>
    <operation>Add Network</operation>
    <result>ERROR</result>
    <resultCode>REASON_210</resultCode>
</Status>
```

This is the error i receive in powershell:

```
Exception calling "UploadData" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
At C:\Scripting\test.ps1:47 char:34
+     $response = $query.UploadData <<<< ($url,"POST",$byteArray)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "GetString" with "1" argument(s): "Array cannot be null.
Parameter name: bytes"
At C:\Scripting\test.ps1:48 char:62
+     $stringresponse = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString <<<< ($response)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I dug further into the error and this is as close as i could get to retrieving the content of the response (the XML).

I thought I might be able to pull it out from this..

```
$error[1].exception.InnerException.Data
```

But it is empty :(

```
PS C:\Scripting> $error[1].exception.InnerException | fl -force


Status         : ProtocolError
Response       : System.Net.HttpWebResponse
Message        : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Data           : {}
InnerException :
TargetSite     : Byte[] UploadDataInternal(System.Uri, System.String, Byte[], System.Net.WebRequest ByRef)
StackTrace     :    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
                    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data)
                    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadData(String address, String method, Byte[] data)
                    at UploadData(Object , Object[] )
                    at System.Management.Automation.MethodInformation.Invoke(Object target, Object[] arguments)
                    at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[]
                 originalArguments)
HelpLink       :
Source         : System


PS C:\Scripting> $error[1].exception.InnerException.response | fl


IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
Cookies                 : {}
Headers                 : {Connection, Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Date}
ContentLength           : -1
ContentEncoding         :
ContentType             : text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
CharacterSet            : ISO-8859-1
Server                  :
LastModified            : 29/11/12 4:04:19 PM
StatusCode              : BadRequest
StatusDescription       : Bad Request
ProtocolVersion         : 1.1
ResponseUri             : https://api-au.dimensiondata.com/oec/0.9/cdefb891-1552-4008-8638-7393eda8d7e1/network
Method                  : POST
IsFromCache             : False
```

Here is my powershell code that I am using:

```
function send_web ($url,$data) {
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
    $query = new-object system.net.WebClient
    $auth = 'Basic ' + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username+":"+$password ))
    $query.Headers.Add('Authorization', $auth )
    [byte[]]$byteArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($data) 
    $query.Headers.Add("ContentType","application/xml")
    $response = $query.UploadData($url,"POST",$byteArray)
    $stringresponse = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($response)
    return $stringresponse
}
```

This seems like it shouldn't be a hard thing to do any help would be much appreciated :)

Richard

Comment: I would use Fiddler to inspect the outgoing request and see if you can spot any problems with the request (not encoded URL, bad header, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your response Keith, I have used fiddler and shown the output in the question. The service is giving me a 400 response when the application throws an error, I don't believe it is related to the format of the request. I have tested this by running a request, which works perfectly. Then running the identical request, this throws a 400 response with the body (application) stating a duplicate request. I am trying to dig into the XML of the 400 response and having no luck.

Comment: I may have the same problem, did you solve this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624749/net-giving-400-bad-request-on-get-request-for-certain-server